# Blackberry - How to get the background application process id

Tags: blackberry, integration, background-application

In my blackberry simulator i m running two application at the background now i want to retrive which are the application running in the background.I don't how to do. Is it possible to show which are the application running in the background.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### List and switch visible application

- To list all visible applications use [ApplicationManager.getVisibleApplications()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/ApplicationManager.html#getVisibleApplications())
- To bring some application foreground use [ApplicationManager.requestForeground(processId)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/ApplicationManager.html#requestForeground(int))

[alt text http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/7003/applist.png](http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/7003/applist.png) [link text http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/9273/applistmenu.png](http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/9273/applistmenu.png)

Code:

```
class Scr extends MainScreen {

    ApplicationDescriptor[] mAppDes;

    public Scr() {
        listApplications();
    }

    void listApplications() {
        ApplicationManager appMan = 
            ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager();
        mAppDes = appMan.getVisibleApplications();
        add(new LabelField("Visible Applications:"));
        for (int i = 0; i < mAppDes.length; i++) {
            boolean isFG = appMan.getProcessId(mAppDes[i]) == appMan
                    .getForegroundProcessId();
            String text = (isFG ? "[F]:" : "[B]") + mAppDes[i].getName();
            add(new LabelField(text));
        }
    }

    protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance) {
        super.makeMenu(menu, instance);
        menu.add(refreshApps);
        makeAppMenuItems(menu);
    }

    MenuItem refreshApps = new MenuItem("Refresh", 0, 0) {
        public void run() {
            deleteAll();
            listApplications();
        }
    };

    class AppMenuItem extends MenuItem {
        ApplicationDescriptor mAppDes;
        public AppMenuItem(ApplicationDescriptor appDes) {
            super(appDes.getName(), 100000, 100000);
            mAppDes = appDes;
        }
        public void run() {
            ApplicationManager appMan = ApplicationManager
                    .getApplicationManager();
            int processId = appMan.getProcessId(mAppDes);
            appMan.requestForeground(processId);
        }
    }

    void makeAppMenuItems(Menu menu) {
        for (int i = 0, cnt = mAppDes.length; i < cnt; i++)
            menu.add(new AppMenuItem(mAppDes[i]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the API Reference for the [RuntimeStore](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/RuntimeStore.html).

And a [Knowledge Base entry](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800639/How_to_-_Make_a_running_UI_application_go_to_the_background_and_resume_in_the_foreground.html?nodeid=800545&vernum=0) how to switch an App to the Background/Foreground.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but the system won't let me comment.

Do you really need to know what the running background applications are, or just if your applications are running in the background.  If the latter I imagine you can build something using the runtime store