# Blackberry Application.activate() not triggering

Tags: blackberry, foreground

I'm calling `Application.getApplication().requestForeground();`  from a Background Class extending from `Application`. But this function is not triggering. This function is also in the same Background Class.

```java
        public void activate(){
             System.out.println("==Activate== ");
        }

        public void setupBackgroundApplication(){ 
             Application.getApplication().requestForeground();
        }
```

How can this activate function can trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may be that there are two different concepts here:

- [Application](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html), which is the base class of all BlackBerry Java applications (UI and background apps)
- [UiApplication](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/UiApplication.html), which is the base class of BlackBerry Java **UI** applications.

If your application is a subclass of `Application`:

```java
public class MyApplication extends Application {
```

then, calling `requestForeground()` isn't going to magically give it a user interface.

My guess is that you need one of two solutions:

1. If you want **one** application, then change it to `extend UiApplication`.  You will then have one application, that goes from foreground to background to foreground ...
2. You could use **two** applications, one which *always* runs in the background, and another which is only a UI application.  Then, your background code could trigger the UI application with the [ApplicationManager APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1464676/119114)